# UIView on top of iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

In my app, i need a transparent view to work as an alert view that can cover the entire screen of iPhone including navigation bar and tab bar, i know how to make a transparent view however, i need help in presenting this transparent view to cover the entire screen and should be on top of navigation and tab bar.

I tried this code but as expected, it only cover the view bounds. not the navigation or tabbar.

```
- (IBAction)joinBtnTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    UIView *blackTransparentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [blackTransparentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [blackTransparentView setAlpha:50.0];

    [self.view addSubview:blackTransparentView];   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window addSubview:....];
```

Comment: This just gave me an idea how to add a `UIViewController`'s view to the current viewController, without actually pushing it.
Thanks

Comment: you can simply add the viewController's view to current viewController like [self.view addSubView:vc.view];